# How to return an Integer as an Error Code

Tags: c#

I currently edit an `.dll` File and try to return an Integer as an Error Code. I do not really know how i could achieve this. Since i could not find something like this for C# i am asking here. The current Code i am trying to Edit is this:

```cs
public bool LaunchExploit()
{
    if (ExploitAPI.NamedPipeExist(this.cmdpipe))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dll already injected", "No problems");
    }
    else if (this.IsUpdated())
    {
        if (this.DownloadLatestVersion())
        {
            if (this.injector.InjectDLL())
            {
                return true;
            }
            MessageBox.Show("DLL failed to inject", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not download the latest version! Did your firewall block us?", "Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Patched", "Error");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried returning an string as an Error but since this is an `public bool` i cannot do that. Any ideas how i could return an Integer as an Error Code

Comment: Change the return type to `int`

Comment: @Cid, i have 2 Booleans in my Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If declaration could be changed, maybe this one can be useful:

```
public bool LaunchExploit(out int errorCode)
{
    if (ExploitAPI.NamedPipeExist(this.cmdpipe))
    {
        errorCode = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Dll already injected", "No problems");
    }
    else if (this.IsUpdated())
    {
        if (this.DownloadLatestVersion())
        {
            if (this.injector.InjectDLL())
            {
                return true;
            }
            errorCode = 2;
            MessageBox.Show("DLL failed to inject", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
            errorCode = 3;
            MessageBox.Show("Could not download the latest version! Did your firewall block us?", "Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        errorCode = 4;
        MessageBox.Show("Patched", "Error");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, to use it if it is possible in your case, you should declare errorCode varaiable before calling LaunchExploit() and call it with this parameter and outer specifier. It wold be like: 
int errorCode = 0;
LaunchExploit(out errorCode);

Comment: You can access it just right after execution of the function

Comment: Ok, can i assign a String to the Error Code?

Comment: Yes, you can. At least there are 2 ways to do it. First one is to use enumeration and another is to use your own object

Comment: The "ErrorCode" out parameter must be assigned before the controller receives the current method. The Error i get

Comment: Did you initialize errorCode variable? Maybe the problem is that it is not initialized like:  int errorCode = 0; or othet integer